# Strange Javascript error

Tags: javascript, error

I have got a Strange Error Javascript. How to find out whot is a problem. Please help:

[image]

Here is my masterpage code:

```
    <%@Master language="C#"%>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="Welcome" src="~/_controltemplates/15/Welcome.ascx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<SharePoint:SPHtmlTag dir="<%$Resources:wss,multipages_direction_dir_value%>" ID="SPHtmlTag" runat="server" >
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <SharePoint:SPPinnedSiteTile runat="server" TileUrl="/_layouts/15/images/SharePointMetroAppTile.png" TileColor="#0072C6" />
    <SharePoint:RobotsMetaTag runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:PageTitle runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
            <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </SharePoint:PageTitle>
    <SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/15/images/favicon.ico?rev=23" />
    <SharePoint:StartScript runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:CssLink runat="server" Version="15"/>
    <SharePoint:CacheManifestLink runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="menu.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="callout.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:SoapDiscoveryLink runat="server" />
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaPlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" Container="false" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server" />
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" AllowMultipleControls="true" />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" Visible="true" runat="server" />
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="Themable/corev15.css" runat="server" />
</head>
<body>
  <SharePoint:ImageLink runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:SPNoScript runat="server"/>
  <SharePoint:SPClientIDGenerator runat="server" ServerControlID="DeltaPlaceHolderMain;DeltaPlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea;DeltaPlaceHolderUtilityContent" />
  <SharePoint:SharePointForm runat="server" onsubmit="if (typeof(_spFormOnSubmitWrapper) != 'undefined') {return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();} else {return true;}">
    <script type="text/javascript"> var submitHook = function () { return false; }; theForm._spOldSubmit = theForm.submit; theForm.submit = function () { if (!submitHook()) { this._spOldSubmit(); } }; </script>
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSPWebPartManager" runat="server">
        <WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager runat="Server"/>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
    <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaDelegateControls" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="GlobalNavigation" />
        <SharePoint:DelegateControl ControlId="GlobalSiteLink3" Scope="Farm" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
<div id="TurnOnAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOnAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(true);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOffAcc').focus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnonaccessibility%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div id="TurnOffAccessibility" style="display:none" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOffAcc" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="SetIsAccessibilityFeatureEnabled(false);UpdateAccessibilityUI();document.getElementById('linkTurnOnAcc').focus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_turnoffaccessibility%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div class="s4-notdlg s4-skipribbonshortcut noindex">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('startNavigation').focus();" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,skipribbon_accesskey%>" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,skipRibbonCommandsLink%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('mainContent').focus();" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,mainContentLink%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div id="TurnOffAnimation" style="display:none;" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOffAnimation" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="ToggleAnimationStatus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_disableanimation%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<div id="TurnOnAnimation" style="display:none;" class="s4-notdlg noindex">
    <a id="linkTurnOnAnimation" href="#" class="ms-accessible ms-acc-button" onclick="ToggleAnimationStatus();return false;">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="<%$Resources:wss,master_enableanimation%>" EncodeMethod="HtmlEncode"/></a>
</div>
<a id="HiddenAnchor" href="javascript:;" style="display:none;"></a>
<div id="suiteBar" class="ms-dialogHidden noindex">
    <div id="suiteBarLeft">
        <div class="ms-table ms-fullWidth">
            <div class="ms-tableRow">
                <div class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignMiddle">
                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" ControlId="SuiteBarBrandingDelegate" runat="server"/>
                </div>
                <SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" id="DeltaSuiteLinks" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-core-deltaSuiteLinks">
                        <div id="suiteLinksBox">
                            <SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteLinksDelegate" ControlId="SuiteLinksDelegate" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="suiteBarRight">
        <SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" id="DeltaSuiteBarRight" CssClass="ms-core-deltaSuiteBarRight" BlockElement="true">
                <div id="welcomeMenuBox">
  <wssuc:Welcome id="IdWelcome" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" />
                </div>
                <div id="suiteBarButtons">
                       <span class="ms-siteactions-root" id="siteactiontd">
                       <SharePoint:SiteActions runat="server" accesskey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_SiteActions_AK%>" id="SiteActionsMenuMain"
                        PrefixHtml=""
                        SuffixHtml=""
                        ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=23"
                        ThemeKey="spcommon"
                        MenuAlignment="Right"
                        MenuNotVisibleHtml="&amp;nbsp;"
                        LargeIconMode="false"
                        >
                        <CustomTemplate>
                        <SharePoint:FeatureMenuTemplate runat="server"
                            FeatureScope="Site"
                            Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
                            GroupId="SiteActions"
                            UseShortId="true"
                            >
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server"
                              id="MenuItem_ShareThisSite"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sharethissite%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_sharethissitedescription%>"
                              MenuGroupId="100"
                              Sequence="110"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              PermissionsString="ViewPages"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_EditPage"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpage15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_editpagedescriptionv4%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/ActionsEditPage.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="210"
                              PermissionsString="EditListItems"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="javascript:ChangeLayoutMode(false);" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_CreatePage"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_addpage15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createpagedesc%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/NewContentPageHH.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="220"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="OpenCreateWebPageDialog('~siteLayouts/createwebpage.aspx')"
                              PermissionsString="AddListItems, EditListItems"
                              PermissionMode="All" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_Create"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_addapp15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_createdesc%>"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="230"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickScriptContainingPrefixedUrl="GoToPage('~siteLayouts/addanapp.aspx')"
                              PermissionsString="ManageLists, ManageSubwebs"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,quiklnch_allcontent_15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_allcontentdescription%>"
                              ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/allcontent32.png?rev=23"
                              MenuGroupId="200"
                              Sequence="240"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/viewlsts.aspx"
                              PermissionsString="ViewFormPages"
                              PermissionMode="Any" />
                          <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate runat="server" id="MenuItem_ChangeTheLook"
                              Text="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_changethelook15%>"
                              Description="<%$Resources:wss,siteactions_changethelookdesc15%>"
                              MenuGroupId="300"
                              Sequence="310"
                              UseShortId="true"
                              ClientOnClickNavigateUrl="~siteLayouts/designgallery.aspx"
```

Comment: Do you have a custom masterpage in your solution? if so, could you please post the code? It seems to me that there is a bad inclusion of ootb sp js files.

Comment: Yes it is problem on Master Page !!! :) Thank You Very Much Xavi. How to bring back maser page to site definition ?

Comment: Several possible answers to your question :) could you post the masterpage code? I think we will be able to solve the issue without the need of just reset the masterpage.

Comment: I posted my MasterPage. :)

Comment: I'm on it, trying to find the issue ;)

Comment: But it like clear site master with error only.

Comment: Yeap, so important thing is to be sure you are deploying your custom masterpage as part of a composed look if you're using SharePoint 2013 [howto](http://thomasdaly.net/2012/12/19/deploying-a-custom-composed-look-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the peace of the mp you provided what I can see is that it is 99% equal to oslo.master. The main difference is that you removed all security trimmed controls, which should not affect in this case. I cannot tell what is going on, I don't know how you deploy the masterpage, so if you have a composed look, difficult to say.

So if you want to reset the masterpage to site definition use SP Designer:
[Roll back mp changes to Site Definition](http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/How-To-Roll-back-changes-made-in-a-Custom-Master-Page-by-SharePoint-Designer-to-Normal-State-in-SharePoint-2010).